# Play 2: @ManyToOne field does not exist in DB table

Tags: java, database, jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am using following models to match users and items. The problem is that in generated `user_item` table in MySQL table has only two columns `id` and `date`. `user` and `item` are not there. **Is it expected?** I expect that these two columns should exist and store ids of `user` and `item`, respectively.

Item.java

```
@Entity
public class Item extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
    public List<UserItem> userItems = new ArrayList<UserItem>();
}
```

User.java

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="item")
    public List<UserItem> userItems = new ArrayList<UserItem>();
}
```

UserItem.java

```
@Entity
public class UserItem extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    public User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    public Item item;

    public Date date;

    ...
}
```

EDIT: What I expect is that `item_user` table would have columns `user` and `item` which would have type long and store ids of corresponding objects. Why my understanding is not correct here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two columns with the same name. Remove your annotations @JoinColumn in UserItem or set different names for user and item (i.e : user_id, item_id)

**EDIT** : Be careful with the fetch type of your @OneToMany annotations. If you have lots of data, you'll have big performance issues when loading a User or a Item for example ;)

**EDIT** :

```
@Entity
public class UserItem extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user")
    public User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item")
    public Item item;

    public Date date;

    ...
}
```

Comment: +1, please, see my edit. And also please elaborate on your EDIT. It is not very clear.

Comment: I edited my answer with an example. Are you using JPA or Ebean ?